# How To filter many times from the initial State in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

let Say I want to filter results from the give user array inside the initial state

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Gray",
          phonenumber: 12342,
          brand: "Honda",
          age: "12",
          occupation: "teacher",
          state: "pending"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Ker",
          phonenumber: 12342,
          brand: "Honda",
          age: "22",
          occupation: "Lover",
          state: "active"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Kite",
          phonenumber: 12342,
          brand: "Honda",
          age: "2",
          occupation: "monkey",
          state: "active"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "Money",
          phonenumber: 12342,
          brand: "Honda",
          age: "2",
          occupation: "monkey",
          state: "active"
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "ajnkaef",
          phonenumber: 12342,
          brand: "Honda",
          age: "2",
          occupation: "monkey",
          state: "passive"
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: "awfehuawe",
          phonenumber: 12342,
          brand: "Honda",
          age: "2",
          occupation: "monkey",
          state: "active"
        }
      ]
    };
```

So I write 2 functions 
That finds for pending state and active state

```
findActive() {
    let activeusers = this.state.users.filter(user => {
        if(user.state === 'active'){
            // console.log(user)
           return user
        }
    })
    this.setState({
        users: activeusers
    })
  }

  findPending(){
    let pendingUsers = this.state.users.filter(user => {
        if(user.state === 'pending'){
            // console.log(user)
           return user
        }
    })
    this.setState({
        users: pendingUsers
    })
  }
```

Then I passed these 2 functions as props into a component.
The program is running fine if I want to filter 1 time only. But When I filter for the second time
the results will be empty always. Because after the first filter I always set the state to the new Array.

Can someone help me find the good solution for this problems.

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly, is there a reason you can't start with empty activeUsers and pendingUsers objects in addition to the users object and filter to them?

Comment: Simply because your `this.state.users` is updated each and every time you find active or pending users. The initial user set (containing all user states) should be left untouched by not setting state in every `find()` and simply doing `filter()` in `render()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand your question I don't know if I get it right. But you can use the code below if you want to filter a pending or active state of the user. I also write the callback just in case you need to call a function after you call the setState.

```js
this.setState(prevState=>{
   return {
    users: prevState.users.filter(user => user.state == 'active' || user.status == 'pending')
   }
}, ()=> { 
  //callback here. You can place another setState or anything here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want filter all the active and pending use:

```
 findActiveOrPending() {
    let users = this.state.users.filter(user => {
       if(user.state === 'active' || user.state === 'pending'){
           return user
        }
    })
    this.setState({
        users: users
    })
}
```

if you want you the exist functions for that, makr the function to return a list of users instead set state inside the function, like this:

```
findActive() {
    return this.state.users.filter(user => {
       if(user.state === 'active'){
           return user
        }
    })
}

findPending(){
    return this.state.users.filter(user => {
       if(user.state === 'pending'){
           return user
        }
    })
```

}

then for active

```
this.setState({users: findActive()})
```

for pending

```
this.setState({users: findPending()})
```

for both

```
this.setState({users: [...findActive(), ...findPending()]})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
findActive() {
    let activeUsers = this.state.users.filter(user => {
        if(user.state === 'active'){
            // console.log(user)
           return user
        }
    })
    this.setState({
        activeUsers
    })
  }

  findPending(){
    let pendingUsers = this.state.users.filter(user => {
        if(user.state === 'pending'){
            // console.log(user)
           return user
        }
    });
    this.state.pendingUsers = pendingUsers; //this will not re-render component and yet you will get filtered pending users data in this. Option 2
    this.setState({
        pendingUsers
    })
  }
```

You can use different state to store those values if you have to show updated active or pending users in the UI as state will be updated and re-render will happen to change the UI.

Or you can store filtered data locally just for your reference(Option 2).

Also you can use prevState as Mart Macion described.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that you are doing it wrong.

you have a state(users), and when you are calling filter on itself(users) you are modifying the original array itself. what you can do is declare another variables in the state and assign the filtered values to those variables instead of modifying the original one. either way you are not suppose to touch the original one to preserve the integrity.

```
    this.state = {
     users: [your data],
     pendingUsers: [],
     activeUsers: [],
    }

    findActive() {
     const { users } = this.state
     this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      activeUsers: users.filter(item => item.state === 'active'),
     }))    
    }

  findPending(){
   const { users } = this.state
   this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    pendingUsers: users.filter(item => item.state === 'pending'),    
   }))
  }

  render() {
   const { users, activeUsers, pendingUsers } = this.state

   return <ChildComponent {...{ users, activeUsers, pendingUsers }} />
  }
```